# Azure App service dependent calls

Tags: azure, synchronization, azure-mobile-services, offline

I have a class structure as following:

UserDepartments(1)->(n)Categories(1)->(n)Templates(1)->(n)reports

I am using Azure offline data sync with incremental sync. There are 2 major issues we are facing with this.

The code is [here](https://gist.github.com/supreettare/a1c88c9ac158dbd5a67d3cc30b3e2fae)

***Issues:***

1. Is there any better way of downloading all this related content then doing foreach under foreach?
2. Intermittently we see that not all the content that has been changed on the server by another Web App downloads & syncs fine when incremental sync is on. Is there a way we can flush the cache list created by the key (the first parameter in PullAsync) used in Incremental Sync? Or do you see something we need to change in order to make sure that we download correct data on each sync?

Answer (score 0):

> Is there any better way of downloading all this related content then doing foreach under foreach?

Pull is performed on a per-table basis, we can’t downloading all the related content at once.

> Is there a way we can flush the cache list created by the key (the first parameter in PullAsync) used in Incremental Sync?

Incremental sync is default support by PullAsync method if you pass the non-null value as the value of queryId  parameter. But there are two points we need to pay attention to.

1. The queryId must be unique for difference pull method.
2. The field filter in later parameter must support sorting.